# External properties file with JSF2

Tags: jsf-2

I'd like to NOT put my properties file in the war file's classes directory.  Can I do this and what would I specify in faces-config.xml for it to use the correct resource-bundle ?
Thanks 
Binh Nguyen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it in an external folder and add its path to the runtime classpath. Then you can access it from the classpath the usual way as if it's in `/WEB-INF/classes` (which is just by default part of the classpath).

Adding the path to an external folder to the classpath is best to be configured at the webserver level. In Tomcat for example, you can specify it in the `shared.loader` or `common.loader` property of Tomcat's `/conf/catalina.properties` file.

```
shared.loader = /path/to/propertiesfiles
```